# Symfony: How to save each successful login to database table

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

i am developing a symfony restful api with tools like
FosRestBundle, FosUserBundle and Lexik JWT for api authentication.

I need to save each successful login in my app. So i created a Login entity
(user_id,loginDate) , but i don't know how to use it because the login in handled from Lexik.

Does anyone know how can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean just logging the login activity? Because persisting login data to a database feels very un-restul to me.

Comment: you need to save what about user login ?

Comment: Our client want to see statistics like number of daily logins. So we must have a login history. I know that this is useless logic but for our client is a must have feature. Please dont down vote me for my client's needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `security.interactive_login` event for that. More information can be found from the official documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events

Create the listener and register it:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Component\EntityManagerAwareTrait;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

/**
 * @package App\EventListener
 */
class SecuritySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        ];
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof User) {
            $user->setLoginDate(new \DateTime());

            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```